# How to enable camera and mic access from WebView in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android

I've build a **webRTC** application that allows streaming audio and video via web using javascript, now i need to run this web application on my **Android** phone.

I'm using [WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/web_view/) to load the URL in my application, but the **WebView** seems to block the access to both **Camera** and **Mic** of my phone. I've already googled for solution, but nothing that i have found solved my problem, if anyone can help me with this i'll be very tankful.

AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="LexLoco.LexLoco" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_VOICEMAIL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
    <application android:label="LexLoco"></application>
</manifest>
```

C# code

```
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            EditText txturl = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            txturl.Text = URL;

            WebView webV = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewer);
            WebSettings webSettings = webV.Settings;

            webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webSettings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            webSettings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

            webV.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            button.Click += delegate {
                webV.StopLoading();
                webV.LoadUrl(txturl.Text);
            };
```

Comment: 1) WebRTC via Webview is only supported in 5.0/Api21+, 2) Along with the  Manifest based Permissions, you have to handle the permission requests at runtime and present those to the user via `PermissionRequest`, not sure if you are doing this as your code only shows the WebView creation/setup 3) Does your WebRTC run properly on the device's browser?

Comment: Yes, it runs perfect in the phone browser.

Comment: Are you handling the PermissionRequest?

Comment: yes, but i don't have much idea of how i could do that, do you have any source?

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: Did you find out the solution for this?

Comment: Hello, was the solution found for this?